# Java 3D geometry library

Tags: java, 3d, geometry

Is there a computational 3D geometry **(only computation, not rendering)** library written in Java? 
I need it for operations like:

- finding primitives intersection, such as planes, cubes etc.
- create "meshes" from triangles, and set properties to mesh elements(vertices, edges, triangles)
- and other geomtrical operations - finding objects by distance, creating mesh from line etc.

Comment: I would advise against using JTS for 3D geometry. It just doesn't calculate Z coordinates: intersection, union, areas... any operation of the sort in 3d doesn't work for that reason. 2D geometry seems to work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are experimental Java bindings for CGAL: https://code.google.com/p/cgal-bindings/

Comment: Thanks, @plabatut, it seems modules I need has Java bindings.

Comment: But, building CGAL on windows is very messy(((